# is it possible to clone a repository that is a pull request rather than managing as a separate branch

Tags: git, github

I have a dev who did some work and he submitted a pull request to me. Is there a way I can clone a copy of this branch? I know I can run git pull but I'd rather clone from his results (if this is possible) just to make a quick build in case there is something wrong. If I'm totally thinking about this wrong, let me know.

The branch url is like this:

```
https://github.com/my-name/project-name/tree/his-branch
```

But if I do

```
git clone https://github.com/my-name/project-name/tree/his-branch
```

I get

```
Cloning into his-branch...
fatal:
https://github.com/my-name/project-name/tree/his-branch/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Why am I getting and how would I just get a copy of what changes he made?

thx in advance

**edit #1**

I tried this but got this error:

```
Wed Dec 05$ git clone --branch his-branch https://github.com/my-name/project-name.git
fatal: destination path 'project-name' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Wed Dec 05$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clone a branch from a repo, you do

```
git clone --branch his-branch https://github.com/my-name/project-name.git
```

The `/tree/his-branch` part is just the github URL for looking at a particular branch. Instead, you need to point git to the repo and then tell it which branch with `--branch` or `-b`.

Also: you should probably be pulling from *his* copy of the repo, not yours. Unless you're both working on the same source repo and he's just requesting you to merge it into master instead of him, that's presumably something like `https://github.com/his-name/project-name.git`....

Comment: hmmm... so I'm probably not understanding fully (or I probably didn't ask question well) but I am getting the error in edit #1 above. So I made him a collaborator so I don't think he has a 'copy' of the repository but again I could be wrong - maybe he would need to make me a collaborator on his? Sorry if not making full sense.

Comment: It sounds like the directory `project-name` already exists in your local filesystem. Do a `git clone --branch his-branch https://github.com/my-name/project-name.git <directory name>` to clone into a separate directory.

Comment: thx, you are correct. Just need to get this built correctly via cocoapds before I accept but this looks like it was working. It's odd that I was asked for uname and pwd to clone this branch although I have ssh keys set up. Any idea why?

Comment: because you're cloning using HTTPS rather than SSH. You must clone using `git clone --branch his-branch git@github.com:my-name/project-name.git` in the first place or add a new `git remote`. Type `git remote -v` inside your cloned directory to verify that you used HTTPS rather than SSH :-)

Comment: thx Ben - I think there was a neuron in my brain like a year ago that knew that....